# Basing the Recangle in upper-left side of the rootPane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am very new at JavaFX. Currently working with 8th version. I am facing the following problem. When I am trying to draw a rectangle, it is center aligned. I added a eventHandler, which gives me the coordinates of the mouse click. So I just need this rectangle to be drawn from upper-left, but not from center, so I can just pass the coordinates of the mouse' clicks and then this rectangle

so the y axis would be from the upper left to south, and the y axis from the upper left to east. So

```
carRect = new Rectangle(0,0,70,36);
```

This code means, that this rectangle would be drawn upper-left aligned but not center aligned with width 70 and height 36. What am I missing ? I know, that I can pass negative values, but I need them just in the way I get them from the eventHandler.

Comment: You're probably using `StackPane` as parent node which by default apply has center alignment for children...

Comment: @fabian, Yes I am using it. Is it possible to align it explizitly ?

Answer (score 0):

Just used Normal Pane instead of StackPane and that solved the problem.